# How to identify underlying cloud using API

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, api, asp.net-core, cloud

We have our Asp.net core API hosted on Azure and AWS.  We want to develop an api which will let us know which cloud it belongs whenever we hit the api

Answer (score 0):

You can put in the API return the name of the cloud used.

If you don't want to put that explicit, you can put into the headers the name of the cloud.

Comment: Thanks Raul, but question is how. Whats the way which returns the name of the cloud. I don't want to keep it in my settings but retrieve it in code.

Comment: The other way that I see as a solution is to balance your API calls between two other URLs, one for AWS and other for Azure. Like:

api.mydns.com balances between aws.api.mydns.com and azure.api.mydns.com

This way you will get from URL which one was called.